# Only allow webpage to be viewed via link click

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, web

Is there a way to only let a webpage be viewed if the link pointing to it is pressed.  I am sending emails to members of my organization with links that attach values to the URL so I can use phps $_GET to figure out who they are on the webpage and update appropriately.  What I am worried about is individuals changing the values of the link and changing other members data.  If there is a better method for doing this, I am all ears.  Using a log in system is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, no.

What you could do is include some token that you keep associated with a particular user id and is very difficult to guess, and include that in the link as well - then, when you get a GET request, you check to make sure the token matches the one you know is correct for that userid. (You'd store the "correct" tokens locally in a database when sending out the emails.)

For instance, you might have...

```
/modify_info_script?user_id=123&token=aSDqWEqwejk2123salskq
```

And then you'd have a database table or some other storage that has...

```
user_id          token
----------------------
...              ...
122              klqwkejajwie8u8213nak
123              aSDqWEqwejk2123salskq
...              ...
```

and thus if someone tried to change the user_id in the URL, the token wouldn't match and you could reject their request. For instance, this would get rejected...

```
/modify_info_script?user_id=122&token=aSDqWEqwejk2123salskq
```

since the right token for `122` would be `klqwkejajwie8u8213nak`, not `aSDqWEqwejk2123salskq`.

This is probably the best option if using a login system isn't an option. However, you should really make sure that using a login system isn't an option at all, because user data really *should* be protected by a login.

Comment: Is there a way to randomly generate token values if I add this column to my database

Comment: You have a script that adds the user row, right? Well, just use that scripting language's random-number function to pick a bunch of characters out of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` or similar and bunch them together, then store the result in the user's "token" column. Token values don't have to be any special format or anything, as long as they're randomly enough generated that someone can't just guess what they'll be.

Comment: Right, this is better than a hash. But now there is no need to have the parameters in the url.

Comment: There is no need to have the user ID in there. You can look up the token in the database without it. Any added "security" from having the user id there can be offset by making the token a bit longer. +1

Comment: Its nothing major,  I email individuals the next meeting times, with 3 buttons that say attending, not attending, maybe.  (Similar to meetup) When they choose a button I update their choice and tally it so I know how many people to expect. I just dont want people to play around with it if they get bored one day

Comment: @Maiku and Leif - Sure, but you can still get some convenience from having the user_id in the url if you don't want to have to a database index for the `token` column. (Chances are you already have an index on the user_id column.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really not the proper way to secure your site.

However, the simple fix for you is to check the "referer" header and make sure it's not blank. If it's not blank, then it came from a click (or they spoofed it, which is why this isn't secure).

The real way to protect data is to implement a login system with a set of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

To check, if someone came from a link, see $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

To protect the application against link manipulation, you can combine it with a secret passphrase (only internally, the passphrase must not be known to anyone) and use md5() on the result. Attach the MD5 to the url. If anyone manipulates the url, you will know because the MD5 of "the url plus your passphrase minus the MD5" will be different.

Comment: MD5 is not a good choice for a cryptographic hash - nor is signing every URL in the same manner a good idea (once you break one URL, you've broken them all). Storing individual tokens is better - not only is it much more difficult to brute force (since you have to do the brute forcing against the server itself), but it also doesn't link the security of one user to all of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot password reset systems work like this so you could say it's reasonably safe provided you use long enough random token. Something like 32 chars should be fine.

Just providing the token should be enough since you don't need the user ID to check it against  issued tokens in database.

```
/modify_info_script?token=aSDqWEqwejk2123salskqfilltill32chars
```

The other alternative is to have login system where use has to type in their credentials in order to change information.

Also if you really fear that someone might try to guess it, just timeout/ban users after 3 wrong token attempts. No one should be trying to type them in by hand anyway.